# Backslash em Expressão regular

Tags: java, regex

estava estudando java e o instrutor do curso deixou um desafio para validar um e-mail utilizando expressões regulares.

pesquisei na documentação da API regex...a parte do pattern..
O problema é que eu achei um código na internet (que funcionou, óbvio).. assim:

```
String regex = "[A-Za-z0-9\\._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*";
```

No caso, eu não entendi apenas o motivo de ele ter posto os caracteres "[" e "]", "(" e ")" , assim como os "\" (que eu sei que significam o backslash, mas não entendi o motivo de ser utilizado nesse código.

Alguém sabe?

Comment: [Significado dos colchetes](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html#2_1_2) e [dos parentenses](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3)

Comment: O backslash é a criptonita da expressão regular. Mas primeiro existe a interpretação de string do Java, portanto para se ter uma contrabarra na regex (para, digamos, neutralizar os poderes do `.`), em Java se escreve `\\.`

Comment: A barra invertida dupla é pra escapa-la. A lista da primeira parte está limitando alfanuméricos, incluindo o ponto, underline e hifen, mas [o ponto também é um caractere de regex](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/ponto.html), então você precisa escapá-lo com uma barra invertida. Mas o java também reconhece as barras invertidas como escape, então você precisa escapar a barra do java pra depois ela escapar o ponto dentro da expressão regular.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]`: É utilizado para corresponder a qualquer caractere que esteja dentro.

**Exemplo**: `[A-Z]` corresponde aos caracteres de A até Z (note que apenas maiúsculas)

`()`: É utilizado para criar um grupo de captura, para extrair substrings ou usar como referência.

**Exemplo**: `(.[A-Za-z]+)*` irá corresponder aos possíveis [TLDs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_TLDs) e o `*` é um quantificador de 0 ou mais correspondências

A utilização de `\\` na expressão apresentada foi para que o ponto seja tratado como o caractere `.`

Caso queira realizar o teste de expressões regulares de forma rápida e aprender mais sobre o uso, aconselho utilizar o [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)

Como lembrado pelo [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) no comentário, a utilização de dois `\` ao invés de um se da ao fato de que o Java não possui suporte a strings "cruas", assim `\\.` é interpretado como `\.`

Comment: Só faltou dizer que o `\\` é uma consequência do Java não ter a possibilidade de inserir strings cruas.

Comment: Bem notado, esqueci de comentar sobre, vou adicionar na resposta

Comment: ... e que na verdade não precisa escapar o ponto dentro de `[]`s